# How to keep row names with running() function?

Tags: r

I would like to know how to keep the row names when using the `running()` function.

e.g. I'm applying a running correlation between two time series, and for me is very important keeping the row names because these are the Years of my time series.

This is an example:

```
library(gtools)

test <- matrix(rnorm(100, sd=4), nrow = 50, ncol=2, 
               dimnames= list(1966:2015, c("var1", "var2")))               

# View(running(test[,1], test[,2], fun=cor, width=5, by=5))
run.test <- running(test[,1], test[,2], fun=cor, width=5, by=5)
```

and I get this

```
    row.names   x
1   1:5 0.41739378
2   6:10    0.96117176
3   11:15   -0.54342033
4   16:20   0.09633428
5   21:25   -0.07296177
6   26:30   0.60366540
7   31:35   -0.34679270
8   36:40   -0.07828379
9   41:45   0.89614252
10  46:50   0.65230839
```

but I would like to keep the row names of my matrix, to have something like this in the row.names:

```
    row.names   x
1   1966:1970   0.41739378
2   1971:1975   0.96117176
3   1976:1980   -0.54342033
4   1981:1985   0.09633428
5   1986:1990   -0.07296177
6   1991:1995   0.60366540
7   1996:2000   -0.34679270
8   2001:2005   -0.07828379
9   2006:2010   0.89614252
10  2011:2015   0.65230839
```

I have tried something like that, but doesn't work

```
running(test[,1], test[,2], fun=cor, width=5, by=5, rownames=rownames(test))
```

some direction?

Comment: You seem to be getting a dataframe for that object you are inspecting with View. I'm only seeing a vector. (Real men don't use `View()`  ; they use `str()`

Comment: Dear @BondedDust thanks very much for your kind answer. Since I'm still a beginner and not and expert like you,  maybe I'm doing a wrong use of the `View()` function, but I'm still a real men :) Inclusive, if I apply the `running()` function to a data frame, I didn't knew how to keep row names or labels. I only copied the results generated by View() to show better my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This splits the names from run.test (which is a named vector not the dataframe object you displayed). I then grabs the vector of first names, coerces to numeric and pulls from the test dataframe. Then does the same for the second names and pastes the results back together:

```
 rn <- strsplit(names(run.test) , ":")

 as.numeric(sapply(rn, "[", 1))
# [1]  1  6 11 16 21 26 31 36 41 46

 names(run.test) <- paste(rownames(test)[as.numeric(sapply(rn, "[", 1))] ,
                          rownames(test)[as.numeric(sapply(rn, "[", 2))]  , sep=":")
 run.test
#------------
 1966:1970  1971:1975  1976:1980  1981:1985  1986:1990  1991:1995  1996:2000  2001:2005  2006:2010  2011:2015 
 0.5016829 -0.5987129 -0.5026115  0.5441250 -0.4203586 -0.4452988 -0.1111146 -0.5197370 -0.2468734 -0.1138099
```

Answer (score 3):

I think that instead of trying to keep the names, you can simply change them, since apparently `running` will use the intervals as the vector names anyway. For your example, you could do it like this:

```
library(gtools)
years <- 1966:2015 #Define the years interval
test <- matrix(rnorm(100, sd=4), nrow = 50, ncol=2, dimnames= list(years, c("var1", "var2")))
result <- running(test[,1], test[,2], fun=cor, width=5, by=5) #save the output
n <-length(years)
intervals <- paste0(years[seq(1, n, by=5)],":", years[seq(5, n, by=5)]) #create the intervals as strings
names(result) <- intervals #rename the output vector
```